# Authentication HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to learn a little about Firebase as well as creating my own HOC's. To that end, I've attempted to create a HOC `withAuth` which creates a new prop `uid`. This is so I can always carry reference to a user across components of my application.

The HOC works fine and I am able to feed other components with its new prop value successfully, but I am having a little trouble understanding a side effect.

For those components which get wrapped with my authentication HOC, on first render, if I try to observe `uid` with a simple `console.log`, it's **always** `null` on first render (followed by a populated value).

I'm wondering if this is normal behaviour given the lifecycle? And if so, is there a way I can combat this.

```
import React from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';


export default withAuth = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class withAuth extends React.Component {

  state = {
    uid: null 
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    auth().signInAnonymously()
    auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => 
      this.setState({uid: user.uid})
    ) 
  }

  render(){      
    const newProps = { 
      uid: this.state.uid,  
      ...this.props 
    }; 
    return (
      <WrappedComponent {...newProps}/>
    )
  }
}
return withAuth;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using a class component in your example and you start by setting the state to `null` explicitly, that's why you're seeing the `null` value.

I would recommend moving away from a class component HOC since it's an older practice. The recommended strategy here would be to use hooks and context.

Don't worry if you're not very familiar with those concepts. Since they are the recommended strategy you will find a lot of reading materials and tutorials on how to set up Firebase with React hooks and context. Here are 2 great articles to get you started:

- [Integrating Firebase Authentication, Hooks, and Context into your ReactJS App](https://johnwcassidy.medium.com/firebase-authentication-hooks-and-context-d0e47395f402)
- [Using Firebase with React Hooks](https://dev.to/bmcmahen/using-firebase-with-react-hooks-21ap)

I also recommend reading an intro to hooks in the [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).